# Can Tor do something in my case?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am using College Wifi which sometimes give upto 2-2.5 MBps downloading speed in morning time but in the evening time it goes worst. Sometimes below 50 KBps speed.

I want to ask that will I get greater speed in the evening time if I use the Tor bundle browser. or it will be the same as without Tor.

Comment: How are you measuring "downloading speed"? Are you using a speedtest site? Or are you downloading with a BitTorrent client?

Comment: @mirimir using BitTorrent Client and Internet download manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your college may be shaping (limiting) BitTorrent traffic when network load is high. Although you might evade traffic shaping by using Tor, using BitTorrent clients via Tor just doesn't work very well. Also, it's nontrivial to set up properly. And perhaps most importantly, it hurts other Tor users.

Try using a VPN service, such as AirVPN or BolehVPN. They're both reputable, support BitTorrent, and allow port forwarding for better swarm reachability.

Using a VPN service (or Tor) to evade traffic shaping may violate your college's WiFi terms of service, and there might be penalties.

Answer (score 0):

Your speed will probably slow to a crawl. Tor is very very slow; it is built for anonymity and privacy, not for speed.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not violate the school's rules, and if you are in a dorm room with window view perhaps of some nearby non-school open WiFi (shopping center, town library, coffee shop, etc), a 2.4GHZ 10" diameter parabolic or a small cantenna (you can make) or yagi inside looking through your window coupled with a WiFi bridge or even directly wired to a computer with an antenna connection you can access might solve your problem.

There are issues of antenna gain and max power the FCC allows in some configurations. A site such as http://www.fab-corp.com has a lot of information as well as extremely qualified and friendly folks you can get on the phone.

IP bandwidth wholesale at a large peering center where many major networks are present is very very inexpensive. If you are out in the boonies, then the last "mile" which could be even hundreds of miles from inexpensive bandwidth, is where the price can go way up.

OTOH if your school is a large university with plenty of bandwith to the outside world, you may be limited by "old" infrastructure just on campus to the dorms. Perhaps a bit of social engineering and/or activism can help.

I remember a NANOG meeting in Miami not that many years ago, but before hotels had bandwidth to rooms where one attendee came with a 3' diameter parabolic open mesh (low wind loading and a light and easy to carry) antenna and a large 3' diameter coil of LMR-400 (low loss professional antenna cable about .4" in diameter) hanging from his shoulder. He aimed it out his window across the plaza to a friendly ISP/CLEC's switching center on the top floor "pent-house" of an office building. A fellow attendee at the conference was a VP at that company and they got a big block of real IP addresses to use that week. At the ISP/Telco end the attendees brought over am Apple airport rainproofed in a reusable resealable plastic food storage container and duct-taped it outside on the hand rail of the fire escape to the roof near where their generator sat on some heavy open beams. The Airport had been modified to have a short coax cable going to a quite small but directional external antenna aimed at the hotel room.

At the hotel end they provided WiFi to their floor and the one above.

Another NANOG meeting, this time in Oakland, again when WiFi didn't yet get to hotel rooms had someone else come with an about 3 or maybe 4 foot long sealed plastic large pipe containing probably a yagi antenna that after nothing could be found to aim at across town was finally tiewrapped to the top window curtain rod so it hung pointing almost straight down and was aimed at the glass roof window of the hotel's bar that did have a good signal.

The point in all that is that there MAY BE a way you can fix your bandwidth problems with ingenuity and some cooperating friends. In your situation, perhaps there is a faculty member that can sanctify your engineering efforts, especially if you can spread the goodness to some others near you.